# Angularjs 1.3 asynchronous validation trigger on `enter`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angularjs 1.3 has an option to asynchronously validate a field through [$asyncValidators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) . There is also an option to set debounce and updateOn (through [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)) to decide when to trigger validation. I have a requirement to trigger validation on `enter` (keyCode == 13). Is this easily possible with the above options? or what is the best way.

I see an example of using asyncValidator [here](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Forms-Article/blob/master/frontend/app.js#L52). But not sure how to filter and only trigger the validation for keyCode = 13.

Thanks.
bsr.

Comment: Have you tried with a simple element.on ? (not sure if is a valid approach with 1.3 version)

Comment: thanks for the comment. I could listen to the event and trigger any controller/service function. but then I might have to handle validation state ($pending, ...) myself. I might be missing something obvious and still reading.

Comment: Since a form is typically submitted on enter (should have a `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` or `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` ... shouldn't that just trigger the validation like it does in Angular 1.2?

Comment: sorry for not being specific. I was trying to trigger the validation per input field. Say, I have few fields, and one of them needs to be validated when user enter some text and press enter key (similar to blur when tab away from the field). say, scan in an item with a barcode reader. I don't use ng-submit, but a button with ng-click to prevent form submit on enter.

Comment: since 1.3 and new validation API is quite new suggest you create a simple form demo to help play with what events can be applied where. Would expect this question to help others later also

Answer (score 0):

`updateOn` and `debounce` are not for triggering validation, but to define when the model should be updated (validators run at this point, of course). E.g.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="stuff" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
```

When you enter something into this field, then `stuff` won't get updated. It's only updated when the input field loses its focus. Even if there was a way to specify a key (you can only specify event types), then you'd have the problem that the model would never get updated if someone doesn't press `enter`. That's quite a risk only to have the text validated on `enter`.

One solution is to set `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`, attach an event listener to the input field and blur the field on `enter`.